# Payment Integration payzee vs stripe

Tags: ios, iphone

I have to choose between one of those libraries for my app. Which do you suggest me to use?
 I have tried both payzee and stripe, any suggestion  which one will be good in production ?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Actually I am implementing it on Iphone and Android both of the platform and having difficulty in implementation the structure for custom token on android thats why  i asked this.

Comment: Not to be picky, but you said "*Which do you suggest me to use?*". The reason it's off topic because you've asked a question without a right answer. One person might say one is amazing, another might say it's rubbish and insist you use the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my personal opinion stripe is better. The code is really easy and well supported and you don't need to deal with personal information of your user.